# Partial word tokenizers vs Word oriented tokenizers Elasticsearch

Tags: elasticsearch, tokenize

reading the link below I am looking for some use case/example in which will be better using Ngram-tokenizing or standard tokenizer doing some comperison.

I hope elastic documentation will include more examples and comparisons in future.

https://www.elastic.co/guide/en/elasticsearch/reference/current/analysis-tokenizers.html

Can someone help me?

Thank you.

Comment: Hi Massimo, did I answered your question? Was it helpful?

Answer (score 0):

The Elastic documentation does include more examples. You can find them in the dedicated page of each tokenizer ([here](https://www.elastic.co/guide/en/elasticsearch/reference/current/analysis-standard-tokenizer.html) is the standard, [here](https://www.elastic.co/guide/en/elasticsearch/reference/current/analysis-ngram-tokenizer.html) is the ngram).

In general, you might want to use an ngram tokenizer to implement a search-as-you-type functionality, such as the auto-suggest in a search input.